# How to grab part of a line in Groovy

Tags: file, parsing, text, groovy, line

I've got lines of text that look like this:

`2011-11-08 10:43:47,153 INFO  [ScanService thread] [SourceNode] scanning /mongo/db/matcher.cpp`

I want to parse them, grabbing only the time value `10:43:47,153`

How can one do this?  Wildcards...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
log = '''
2011-11-08 08:13:16,121 INFO [ScanService thread] [SourceNode] scanning /mongo/db/matcher.cpp
2011-11-08 09:32:42,102 INFO [ScanService thread] [SourceNode] scanning /mongo/db/matcher.cpp
2011-11-08 10:43:47,153 INFO [ScanService thread] [SourceNode] scanning /mongo/db/matcher.cpp
'''

matcher = (log =~ /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}/)

matcher.count.times {
  println matcher[it]
}
```

gives you:

```
08:13:16,121
09:32:42,102
10:43:47,153
```

Comment: You can use this syntax: `matcher = (log =~ /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}/)` for the regex and forget about escaping the backslashes :)

Comment: Thanks, this works!  How can I become a groovy master like you guys?

Comment: What is the `matcher = ...` assignment doing specifically?

Comment: The `matcher` is just an instance of `java.util.regex.Matcher`, which is built after applying the pattern to the log string :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider something like:

```
def s = "2011-11-08 10:43:47,153 INFO [ScanService thread] [SourceNode]"
def tokens = s.split(" ")
def time = tokens[1]
println time
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just split on spaces, or if the date formatting is constant width, use a substring.

A regular expression would also work, but if it's not necessary, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

If the date and time is fixed width I would just grab the time value like this:

```
def s = '2011-11-08 10:43:47,153 INFO [ScanService thread] [SourceNode]'
assert s[11..22] == '10:43:47,153'
```